# Rails 7.1.2 Invalid HTTP format, parsing fails Are you trying to open an SSL connection to a non-SSL Puma?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I generated the credentials with:

```
$ EDITOR="code --wait" bin/rails credentials:edit --environment production

Adding config/credentials/production.key to store the encryption key: d109e47d27a487cfe6227723f5ed4446

Save this in a password manager your team can access.

If you lose the key, no one, including you, can access anything encrypted with it.

      create  config/credentials/production.key

Editing config/credentials/production.yml.enc...
File encrypted and saved.
```

Then I executed the rails server via:

```
RAILS_ENV=production bin/rails s=> Booting Puma
=> Rails 7.1.2 application starting in production 
=> Run `bin/rails server --help` for more startup options
[310165] Puma starting in cluster mode...
[310165] * Puma version: 6.4.0 (ruby 3.2.0-p0) ("The Eagle of Durango")
[310165] *  Min threads: 5
[310165] *  Max threads: 5
[310165] *  Environment: production
[310165] *   Master PID: 310165
[310165] *      Workers: 8
[310165] *     Restarts: (✔) hot (✔) phased
[310165] * Listening on http://0.0.0.0:3000
[310165] Use Ctrl-C to stop
[310165] - Worker 0 (PID: 310188) booted in 0.02s, phase: 0
[310165] - Worker 1 (PID: 310190) booted in 0.02s, phase: 0
[310165] - Worker 2 (PID: 310195) booted in 0.01s, phase: 0
[310165] - Worker 3 (PID: 310200) booted in 0.01s, phase: 0
[310165] - Worker 4 (PID: 310211) booted in 0.01s, phase: 0
[310165] - Worker 5 (PID: 310217) booted in 0.01s, phase: 0
[310165] - Worker 6 (PID: 310229) booted in 0.01s, phase: 0
[310165] - Worker 7 (PID: 310251) booted in 0.0s, phase: 0
```

but everytime I try to access to localhost, the error:

```
[310165] - Worker 7 (PID: 310251) booted in 0.0s, phase: 0
2024-02-27 12:24:40 +0100 HTTP parse error, malformed request: #<Puma::HttpParserError: Invalid HTTP format, parsing fails. Are you trying to open an SSL connection to a non-SSL Puma?>
2024-02-27 12:24:40 +0100 HTTP parse error, malformed request: #<Puma::HttpParserError: Invalid HTTP format, parsing fails. Are you trying to open an SSL connection to a non-SSL Puma?>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: How exactly are you accessing the server, i.e. how are you generating requests? Are you trying to open an SSL connection to a non-SSL Puma?

Comment: in chrome, firefox, etc... I put http://localhost:3000 but automatically, chrome, firefox, etc... tries to acces to a https://localhost:3000. It was working, but suddenly this happen....

Answer (score 0):

You are running your rails server in `production` mode:

```
=> Rails 7.1.2 application starting in production
```

But you're accessing it at a local, non `https` url: i.e. `http://localhost:3000`.  Rails doesn't allow by default non-https requests in production.

You can configure rails to allow you to access prod without `https` using `config.force_ssl = false`.  However, I strongly discourage you from doing that.

It seems clear to me that you're running in development.  So you should start rails as

```
$ bin/rails s
```

to run it in development.